# Show: $\frac{\cos 3x + i\sin 3x}{\cos x + i\sin x} = \cos 2x + i\sin 2x$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I'm having trouble with the following-

Show: $$\frac{\cos 3x + i\sin 3x}{\cos x + i\sin x} = \cos 2x + i\sin 2x$$

I have tried both multiplying by the complex conjugate of the denominator and alternatively trigonometric identities, but the results don't get close

Can anybody give me any pointers in the right general direction?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Use https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/4907/eulers-first-proof-of-eix-cosxi-sinx

Comment: Are you supposed  to know *Euler's formula*?

Comment: Multiplying by the complex conjugate of the denominator will work.  If you "didn't get close" then your idea is correct, but you have an error in execution.  Check your algebra.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $$e^{i ax} = \cos(ax) + i \sin(ax).$$

Comment: Thank you, I have understand it now :)

Comment: Thanks everyone for answers

Answer (score 2):

HINT: multiply numerator and denominator by $$\cos(x)-i\sin(x)$$
you will get
$$\cos(x)\cos(3x)+\sin(x)\sin(3x)+i(\cos(x)\sin(3x)-\cos(3x)\sin(x))$$
and this is for what you are searching